# modelling IVPs in MATLAB

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matlab, initial-value-problems

I am trying to get the following ODE model dx/dt = 2x, x(0)=10 to start from the initial condition but it keeps starting from zero instead of 10 [image of the code and its run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNC8J.png)
Can anyone advise?

Comment: Did you look at the scale of the vertical axis? Against $10^9$ the initial value $10$ is indistinguishable from $0$.

Comment: @LutzL mentioned the obvious problem. Also you know the solution to this problem analytically, just compare the difference and see if it worked

$$x(t) = 10e^{2t}$$

Comment: Take $t=0:0.01:1$ ! You will have a completely different look !

Comment: thanks guys let me try the way you've put it

Answer (score 0):

@Lutzl is right.If you look at the workspace variable $xx$ generated after you pass $x$ to the **eval** function the solution starts from the point 10. The only reason you aren't seeing this is because of the axis limits that you are working with.

Try the following:
**axis([0 10 0 100])** 
and you can see the IVP solution rising from 10.

Comment: how do I change the axis??

Comment: I have it in my answer. Do you have a specific time till when you want to obtain the solution, if not, restrict the y limits.

Comment: actually I don't have a specific time. Let me do it this way